# Completed Code, But How To Use It With Abstract Classes?

Tags: java, abstract

So I've finished my code which gets employee information as input and it can sort based on what the user wants. But for part of the requirements, I have two use an abstract class "Employee" with two subclasses "TempEmployee" and "Perm
employee". What of my code do I put under the abstract classes for this to work? Also, when I sort I want all the information to go with it, so If I sort by salary, I want the names and department of the people who make that salary when it orders it, not just an ordered list of the numbers. Is this possible as well?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Assignment55_000848913
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String Continue = "y";
int Count = 0;
int SortingChoice;
ArrayList<String> Names       = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Department  = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Designation = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Float>  Salary      = new ArrayList<Float>();

    //******************************************************//

do
{
   System.out.println("Enter Employee Name: ");
   String x = in.next();
   Names.add(x);

   System.out.println("Enter Employee Designation ('temporary or permanent'): ");
   String y = in.next();
   Designation.add(y);

   System.out.println("Enter Employee Department: ");
   String z = in.next();
   Department.add(z);

   System.out.println("Enter Employee Salary: ");
   float i = in.nextFloat();
   Salary.add(i);

   System.out.println("Do you wish to add another employee? ('y'/'n'): ");
   Continue = in.next();

   Count = Count + 1;
}
while(Continue.equals("y"));

//***********************************************************************//

System.out.println("Enter sorting Criterion Number: 1. Name, 2.Department, 3. Salary. ");
SortingChoice = in.nextInt();

if(SortingChoice == 1)
{
  Collections.sort(Names);
     for(int i=0; i<Names.size(); i++)
     {
        System.out.println(Names.get(i));
     }
}

if(SortingChoice == 2)
{
  Collections.sort(Department);
     for(int i=0; i<Department.size(); i++)
     {
        System.out.println(Department.get(i));
     }
}

if(SortingChoice == 3)
{
  for(int k=0; k<Salary.size(); k++)
  {
    if(Designation.get(k).equals("temporary"))
      {
         Salary.set(k, Salary.get(k)*1920);
      }
  }


  Collections.sort(Salary);
     for(int i=0; i<Salary.size(); i++)
     {
       System.out.print("$");
       System.out.println(Salary.get(i));
     }
}
  }
}

 // public  class Employee
  // {

 // }

 // public class TempEmployee extends Employee
     // {

//  }

//  public class PermEmployee extends Employee
//  {

//  }
```

Comment: You have "completed the code", except you haven't done the assignment? That's **not** *completing* the code. --- Is there supposed to be any difference between temp. and perm. employees? E.g. salaried vs hourly, or something?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is not complete.  You don't appear to be using concrete classes for the various types of employee.

Comment: Andreas, what I meant is that the code does what it's supposed to do, its just not set up as he inteded wit habstract classes, which is what I'm asking help with. The only difference between the two is how you input their salary and you have to make a quick conversion to yearly from hourly for them

Comment: yes, the main class i am using seems to be concrete Tim

Comment: If you don't know how to define an abstract class, maybe start reading here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is meant more as a convenience of not having to repeat things.  So a good start would be to just go ahead and define your PermEmployee class.  Then define your TempEmployee class.  Whatever variables and methods they have in common, you can place into an AbstractEmployee class and have each of those inherit from it.  That way the methods and variables left will be ones unique to the Temp and Perm employee classes.

The rest will just be an exercise in learning the mechanics of defining an abstract class which I'll leave for you to read up on.  Deciding when a method should be abstract and what methods can be shared in all the children classes and which ones should have a default behavior that needs to be overwritten in unique situations.